# How to validate data if there are no matching rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I am fetching data from the database like this

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_query)){
    $userId = $row ['id'];
    $check_email = $row ['userEmail'];
    $check_password = $row ['userPassword'];
}
```

and then I compare if the entered details match the details fetched from the db.

```
if ($email === $check_email || $hashed_password ===  $check_password) {

   // header ("Location:../dashboard.php");
    echo "success";

} else {

   // header ("Location: ../signup.php");
    echo "failed";
}
```

but the problem is, if the email address entered doesn't exist in the database, it returns error

> Notice: Undefined variable: check_email in
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\honest\includes\login_process.php on line 37

However if the email exists, then it returns success.

So the questions is, what is the best practice here? Should I set default value to `$check_email` if it's empty?

Comment: `$row` will be `false` if there are no rows so... `if ($row && $email === $check_email && $hashed_password === $check_password)`

Comment: @Phil Yes, it worked. thanks, can you post this as an answer and explain if you don't mind

Comment: You also realise if there are multiple rows in your statement, this will only check the last one in the result set.

Comment: Check if $check_email is set before comparison - if(isset($check_email)){}

Comment: @Phil so how do you suggest I validate if email & password entered match the credentials in db?

Comment: Also, your logic is incorrect, you should test for AND, not OR in your if statement

Comment: @Mat thanks, I only set OR for testing purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `userEmail` is unique, your table is named "user_table" and `$conn` is your `mysqli` connection / instance, you can check for a matching row like this...

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
    'SELECT `id` FROM `user_table` WHERE `userEmail` = ? AND `userPassword` = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $hashed_password);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($userId);
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo 'success';
    // $userId is also set to the result `id` now
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check_email parameter coming from the query is null, so you need to do a null check before assigning it to another variable, i.e.

```
$check_email = $row['userEmail'] != null ? $row['userEmail'] : '';
```

Comment: This will just trigger an unknown index error instead

Comment: actually, NO it doesn't. if the userEmail row exists it will obtain the value returned from query

Comment: If there are no rows, then `$row` will be `false` and will most definitely not have a `userEmail` index

Comment: that goes without saying

Comment: you're off topic dude

Comment: I owe you an apology. Seems PHP acts strangely around attempts to access array indices of boolean values and it does not trigger any warnings. Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/ZihZQ